# « Schadenfreude » : usage en français et traduction

Tags: traduction, usage, allemand

Le mot allemand *Schadenfreude*, qui décrit **« un malin plaisir tiré de l’infortune d’autrui »**, est un casse-tête récurrent dans la traduction. Il décrit une chose tellement précise qu'il a été importé directement en anglais, où on le trouve désormais dans la presse écrite et où il figure dans les dictionnaires de référence.

À l’opposé, son usage direct en français ne me semble pas établi, et il ne figure dans aucun dictionnaire que j’ai sous la main (à part [wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/schadenfreude#Fran.C3.A7ais), qui a le désavantage de faire parfois figurer des mots inusités mais qui sont chers à l’un des contributeurs). Donc, mes questions sont :

- comment le traduire de manière plus courte que la définition que j'ai donnée ci-dessus ?
- peut-on le considérer comme faisant partie du vocabulaire courant en français, ou bien est-ce trop présumer ? est-il, par exemple, employé dans la presse sans traduction ou explication incise ?

Comment: [Karambolage en a parlé.](http://www.arte.tv/fr/746392,CmC=746396.html)

Comment: Votre observation pour wiktionary est valable pour tous ce qui font recours à l'[externalisation ouverte](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdsourcing). Je prends mes précautions afin d'éviter un autre anglicisme, on ne sait jamais.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En psychologie, le terme correspondant exactement est *plaisir* [*pervers*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/pervers), mais il y a de fortes chances qu'il soit mal interprété.

Pour l'instant, je ne pense pas que *Schadenfreude* puisse être considéré comme du vocabulaire courant en français standard mais peut-être que pour certaines variétés (amis québécois?) il est acceptable.

Comment: Pourquoi les québécois en particulier ?

Comment: Pour leur tendance à récupérer des anglicismes plus facilement.

Comment: Un anglicisme plutôt allemand, quand même :)

Comment: Eh, on peut bien avoir des [anglicismes français](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Anglicisme#Anglicismes_en_fran.C3.A7ais)!

Comment: En tous cas c'est au moins un mot qui me "dit" quelque chose, au contraire de Weltanschauung.

Comment: Les contributeurs de `de.wikipedia.org` sont d'un autre avis: Das Wort `Schadenfreude` existiert als deutsches Lehnwort im Englischen, **Französischen**, Italienischen, Spanischen, Portugiesischen und Polnischen (citation).

Comment: @Joubarc Le pire serait que la Schadenfreude constitue ta Weltanshauung ! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Je ne vois pas de traduction en un mot de *Schadenfreude*. J'ai déjà entendu et lu ce mot employé par des francophones, mais de façon extrêmement rare.

La plus courte traduction qui me vient à l'esprit est l'expression *se réjouir du malheur d'autrui/des autres*, ce qui revient à le définir.

[ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Schadenfreude&year_start=1800&year_end=2013&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=) laisse penser que ce mot, tout en n'ayant jamais été très employé, l'a plus été au début du XXè siècle qu'il ne l'est maintenant.

Quant à [Google Trends](http://www.google.fr/trends/explore?q=Schadenfreude#q=Schadenfreude&geo=FR&cmpt=q), qui analyse les recherches Google contenant ce mot, il semble montrer un usage depuis 2009. A défaut de valeurs absolues, on ne peut en tirer de conclusions quant au volume de cet usage, mais cela laisse supposer que ce terme a une existence. En [comparant son usage à celui de *fermion* et de *polypropylène*](http://www.google.fr/trends/explore?q=Cad%C3%A8ne%2CSchadenfreude#q=Schadenfreude%2C%20%20fermion%2C%20%20polypropyl%C3%A8ne&geo=FR&cmpt=q), par exemple, on peut se faire une idée très approximative.

Answer (score 3):

Je dois dire que j'ai pris un ''malin plaisir'' à vous voir vous débattre dans ces difficultés ...?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11790)

Comment: @Jylo I do not agree with your comment. Although very short *malin plaisir*  **is** an answer to the question. It was mentioned in the question but none of the other answers mentions it. If you find the answer is too short then say so and help a new user improve the write better answers.

Comment: @Laure I reviewed too fast and did not think it would appear as comment, my bad.

Comment: @Jylo No problem. People may also express different views. Oh... I wanted to write "to write" (in my comment!) but it seems I did not type that!

Answer (score 1):

Ma langue maternelle n'est pas le français, aussi je ne le sais pas qui est dans l'usage commun, mais je crois que dans la plupart de contextes « *joie malveillante* » est plutôt non ambigu. C'est essentiellement un calque du mot allemand „Schadenfreude“ (*dommage plaisir*) ou du mot russe similaire «злорадство» [zloradstvo] (*joie malicieuse*).

---

I am not a native Francophone, hence I cannot speak concerning what's in common usage, though I do believe that in most contexts « *joie malveillante* » should be unambiguous enough. That is essentially just a calque of the German word „Schadenfreude“ (*injury happiness*) or the similar Russian word «злорадство» [zloradstvo] (*malicious glee*).

Answer (score 1):

Un syntagme qui peut être utilisé selon les contextes est également : la délectation cruelle